# Dispatch is working but it is not updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a application which uses redux for state management. There, at a some condition, I  want to update the state.

My initial state and reducer function looks like this:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const filterDataTemplate = {
  programId: '',
  year: '',
};

const initialState = {
   //some other state
  filterData: { ...filterDataTemplate },
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'editFilterSlice',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {    
    updateFilterProgramId: (state, action) => {
      state.filterData.programId = action.payload;
    },
    updateFilterYear: (state, action) => {
      state.filterData.year = action.payload;
    },
    
  },
});

export const {
  updateFilterYear,
  updateFilterProgramId, 
} = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

So filter details containg year and programId is obtained with the help of this code:

```
const filterDetails = useAppSelector(
   (state) => state.locationsFilter.filterData
 );
```

Let's say I have filter data initially:

```
filterDetails: {year:2021, programId: "Ameria"}
```

And i want to have my new filter data to be

```
filterDetails: {year: "", programId: "Ameria"}
```

So for this what I am doing:

```
const handleDelete = (e) => {    
    e.preventDefault();
    if (//some condition) {
      console.log("delete is called");
      dispatch(updateFilterYear(''));
    } else {
      dispatch(updateFilterProgramId(''));      
    }
}
```

handleDelete function is getting called properly when I am clicking a button because I am getting value inside console.

But after running this code my filter data is not updating. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Please help with this.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong in your code. Could you show your component code where it gets the value from the store and uses it?

Answer (score 0):

Action.payload is of object type. So You should reference action.payload.year.
I hope this example will be of any use

```
 
 ​    ​setTodoDate​: ​{ 
 ​      ​reducer​: ​(​state​,​ ​action​: ​PayloadAction​<​TodoDate​>​)​ ​=>​ ​{ 
 ​        ​state​.​currentDate​ ​=​ ​action​!​.​payload​.​date​; 
 ​      ​}​, 
 ​      ​prepare​: ​(​value​)​ ​=>​ ​(​{ 
 ​        ​payload​: ​{​ ...​value​ ​}​, 
 ​      ​}​)​, 
 ​    ​}
```

Comment: It's only an object if you pass an object. If you pass a string it will be a string.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is because you are trying to mutate your state directly. This is bad practice, and Redux state (and more generally react) is intended to be immutable. Reducers should return a copy of the state, along with the updated values. Documentation linked below.

[Redux Documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#reducers-and-immutable-updates)

Try writing your reducers like the following

```
updateFilterYear: (state, action) => {
     return {
         ...state,
         filterData: {
            ...state.filterData,
            year: action.payload
        }
    },

updateFilterProgramId: (state, action) => {
      return {
         ...state,
         filterData: {
            ...state.filterData,
            programId: action.payload
        }
    },
```

Comment: It is working now, but on clicking deletehandler two times it is updating not on first time

Comment: OP is using Redux Toolkit in which you *are* supposed to mutate the state.